# How can I create a fixed sidebar navigation that highlights the currently viewed section of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar

This seems like it should be simple but I'm having a hard time finding an example of how to implement this.  I cannot figure out how to get the sidebar links to highlight when I scroll to the respective id that the link points to on the page.  Here is an example of this on the Microsoft Docs site (the righthand sidebar):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a position sticky to your sidebar with the specific top property.
for more information, you can read this article.
[How to make a sticky sidebar with two lines of CSS](https://dev.to/clairecodes/how-to-make-a-sticky-sidebar-with-two-lines-of-css-2ki7)

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

aside {
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  width: 66%;
}

main div {
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <aside>Sticky Sidebar</aside>
  <main>
    <div>section</div>
    <div>section</div>
    <div>section</div>
    <div>section</div>
    <div>section</div>
    <div>section</div>
    <div>section</div>
    <div>section</div>
  </main>
</div>
```